# What's the Android way of letting a user rearrange items on a ListView and remove items?

Tags: android, android-listview

Well the question is that simple, what is the Android recommended way of letting a user reorder items in a ListView and remove items? I know the iOS way of doing it but since I haven't seen it much on Android I figured that probably isn't the recommend way of doing it?

Also please let me know if there are some libraries that help with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Drag and drop, to remove it usually a long press > menu > delete. Or a swipe of the item

Comment: Google Keep does this, each list item has a little tab on the left you can hold to drag up or down.